# Convergence of ratio of two sums of uniform random variables

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, surfaces, uniform-distribution, rectangles

> Consider the sequence of rectangles, which sides are length $(X_1, Y_1), (X_2, Y_2),...,$ where $X_1, X_2,...$ have uniform distribution on $(0,2)$ and $Y_1, Y_2, ...$ have uniform distributions on $(0,4)$. All random variables are independent, Let $P_1, P_2,...$ be sequence of surfaces of these rectangles and $O_1, O_2,...$ sequence of perimeters of the rectangles. What is the limit of 
>   $$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{P_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{O_i}},$$
>   when $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Doesn't matter what kind of convergace of random variable we consider.

I saw that $P_i$ and $O_i$ are independent, when $i \neq j$.

I tried to put on the ratio $log(x)$ and inspect characteristic function and then use Lévy's continuity theorem [1]. I thought about CLT and law of large numbers.

Please, help! Maybe some advises or intuitions. 
Thanks!

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem

Comment: Maybe you are overthinking it.  What do you know about $\sum_1^n P_i/n$ ? And about $\sum_1^n O_i/n$?

Comment: $\sum P_n/n \xrightarrow{a.s.} \mathbb{E}P_1 = 2$ and analogously $\sum O_n/n \xrightarrow{a.s.} \mathbb{E}O_1 = 6$, because of Kolmogorov theorem about strong law of large numbers.

Comment: Does the ratio of two a.s. convergent sequences converge a.s. ?

Comment: If yes, its over. But I can't prove it or find the proof.